# Centering UICollectionView Cells in Container

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Hi I need help centering my collection view cells via UICollectionViewFlowLayout. My end goal is to have the first cell in the middle and have every other cell snapping in the middle. Thanks!

Here is what it looks like now: 
[image]

and what I want it to look like: 
[image]

I found this "solution" on SO but it seems to not work properly.

```
class CenterAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

    let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)

    // Constants
    let leftPadding: CGFloat = 8
    let interItemSpacing: CGFloat = 5

    // Tracking values
    var leftMargin: CGFloat = leftPadding // Modified to determine origin.x for each item
    var maxY: CGFloat = -1.0 // Modified to determine origin.y for each item
    var rowSizes: [[CGFloat]] = [] // Tracks the starting and ending x-values for the first and last item in the row
    var currentRow: Int = 0 // Tracks the current row
    attributes?.forEach { layoutAttribute in

        // Each layoutAttribute represents its own item
        if layoutAttribute.frame.origin.y >= maxY {

            // This layoutAttribute represents the left-most item in the row
            leftMargin = leftPadding

            // Register its origin.x in rowSizes for use later
            if rowSizes.count == 0 {
                // Add to first row
                rowSizes = [[leftMargin, 0]]
            } else {
                // Append a new row
                rowSizes.append([leftMargin, 0])
                currentRow += 1
            }
        }

        layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x = leftMargin

        leftMargin += layoutAttribute.frame.width + interItemSpacing
        maxY = max(layoutAttribute.frame.maxY, maxY)

        // Add right-most x value for last item in the row
        rowSizes[currentRow][1] = leftMargin - interItemSpacing
    }

    // At this point, all cells are left aligned
    // Reset tracking values and add extra left padding to center align entire row
    leftMargin = leftPadding
    maxY = -1.0
    currentRow = 0
    attributes?.forEach { layoutAttribute in

        // Each layoutAttribute is its own item
        if layoutAttribute.frame.origin.y >= maxY {

            // This layoutAttribute represents the left-most item in the row
            leftMargin = leftPadding

            // Need to bump it up by an appended margin
            let rowWidth = rowSizes[currentRow][1] - rowSizes[currentRow][0] // last.x - first.x
            let appendedMargin = (collectionView!.frame.width - leftPadding  - rowWidth - leftPadding) / 2
            leftMargin += appendedMargin

            currentRow += 1
        }

        layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x = leftMargin

        leftMargin += layoutAttribute.frame.width + interItemSpacing
        maxY = max(layoutAttribute.frame.maxY, maxY)
    }

    return attributes
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your view controller is the delegate of the collection view and implement the following method from `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    let sideInset = (collectionView.frame.size.width - myCollectionViewCellSize.width) / 2
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: sideInset, bottom: 0, right: sideInset)
}
```

Comment: How do you reference the `myCollectionViewCellSize`?

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified. You need to replace that with whatever your cell size is.

Comment: Ok. By my cell size do you mean my cell width defined in interface builder? Because Xcode won't allow me to input an integer. For example I put `(collectionView.frame.size.width - 690.width)` and gave me the error `Value  of type 'Int' has no member 'width'`

Comment: Just do `(collectionView.frame.size.width - 690) / 2`

Answer (score 0):

Using UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, there is the method collectionView:collectionViewLayout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath.

There you would define how much margins you want (let's say for this example it's a variable defined as 10.0) just do some calculation for your width like so:

let width = collectionView.frame.size.width - (margin * 2)

and then from there you would return a CGSize of your width and your height.

Does your app support multiple layouts (portrait/landscape as well as multitasking on iPads)? Don't forget to also implement willTransitionToTraitCollection and viewWillTransitionToSize as your view's width will all be changing and your should be updating your cells as well in those cases.